# Flux Store and actions with temporary data

Tags: flux

Note: This is a follow-up question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536037/flux-store-collection-by-criteria-vs-single-item but it is independent to understand and answer.

Imagine we have an application for managing (CRUD) Tasks. One operation is a Task editing.

First the edit view loads the Task using an action creator that asynchronously fetches it from the server and dispatches TASK_LOAD_SUCCESS event together with the Task payload. Next a Task Store stores the Task and emits a change event so that the edit view can read it and fill the form.

When the user submits the form the changes should be saved and the edit view should be closed.

On the submit the edit view tells action creator to asynchronously save the Task. On AJAX success the TASK_SAVE_SUCCESS is dispatched (to the Task store).

Q1: What should the Task Store do? Should it update its internal flag that a task has been saved then emit the change event and then the view should read that flag from the store and close itself if it is true?

Q2: Should the Store find the Task in the collection of the previously loaded Tasks and update it there? Other Tasks in the collection will remain stale (see Q2 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536037/flux-store-collection-by-criteria-vs-single-item).

Q3: What if we edit the Task again? The Store still has the flag that the Task has been successfully saved and it closes itself immediately. But it was from the previous save. How to deal with it?

Simmilar problem arises if we want to delete a Task. We use an optimistic locking and therefore we must first read the Task from the server then show the confirmation dialog and finally delete the Task on the server (providing ETag from the first read).

Q4: How to use the store to signal that the Task has been loaded for the deletion? During this AJAX call there might another asynchronous read operation become complete and it would clash with this one. Should there be a separate Store for a Task deletion?

Q5: This is same as Q1. After the deletion how to tell the view that it is done so it can close the confirmation dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Q1-Q3: you may store an `edit_timestamp` in TaskStore and `open_timestamp` for confirmation dialog. On `emitChange` you may compare if `edit_timestamp > open_timestamp`.

Q4: you may cache request Promise for each taskId on fetch request. So instead doing the same request twice (read/delete fetch for the same taskId), you may subscribe on the existed Promise. That allow you to keep only the single instance of task, and I hope avoid Q5 problems:

```
//To imagine how to arrange promise-based async interaction you may look here http://mjw56.github.io/handling-asynchronous-data-flow-in-flux/index.html
var promises = {};

//Returns Promise
var asyncGetCall = function(taskId) {...}
var getTaskForDelete, getTaskForRead;

getTaskForDelete = getTaskForRead = function(taskId) {
   if (!promises[taskId]) {
     promises[taskId] = asyncGetCall(taskId);
   }    
   return promises[taskId];
}

getTaskForDelete(10).then(function() {...}); //do asyncGetCall
getTaskForRead(10).then(function() {...}); // do nothing, wait for the first req results
```